# Retrieve Facebook Public Page Feed

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I just got started with the facebook Graph API and I am struggling a bit.

I have got an ASP.Net web application which simply needs to display feed from Facebook public page. It is a JavaScript/jQuery app hosted on the web app. I created an App using Facebook and got an APP ID.

I have got the following snippets :

```js
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '87745646546',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.4'
      });
    };
  
    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

```js
FB.api(
      "/99999999/feed?access_token=xyteyfghhghghfghfgfhgfhg",
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          alert(response.data.length);
        }
      }
);
```

So the id of the public page is 99999999 and I generated an access token using my Facebook login and the Graph API Explorer. I am getting results back as expected.

Hoever I read that the access token is not permanent and it expires. So how to generate access token dynamically everytime the app loads. The app is supposed to be used by users who might not even have Facebook logins. They just want to see the latest feed on the page.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) does what you want - with no requirement for users to have a Facebook login. If you want to style up the feed more heavily, you'd be best to run the code to fetch the latests posts server-side - it's a bad idea to leave that `access_token` on the public page.

To get a page access token that doesn't expire, [swap your user token for a long-lived token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending), then grab a page access token from `/me/accounts` using your new access_token. The page access token won't expire!

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for your reply. However just to clarify I don't have the option of writing any server side code. It has to be a client side JavaScript app. So in that case is Page Plugin the only option for me or can I use something else? I am really confused.

Comment: The page plugin is going to be the easiest option by far. Are you an administrator of the page you're taking the feed from?

Comment: Hi Tom nope I am not. However I can get hold of the admin. In that case if I can generate the page access token, I can use it for good. Isnt'it?